# Maven build Error - Strange

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am facing a strange maven build error. I took checkout from the SVN and pom said,

> "Could not calculate build plan, Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.4.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:jar:2.4.2"

I am attaching a screen shot for the same. Tried to search from many resources but of no help. Can anyone suggest some possible reasons? [image]

Comment: you can go for 1. Run As-->Maven Clean 
2. Run as--> Maven Test it will give a error list and share it here

Comment: I would not describe it as a "strange error". Maven simply cannot download some dependencies. So you should check the Maven settings (~/.m2/settings.xml) and the POM in question.

Comment: @Make 
build.plugins.plugin.version for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin is missing

Comment: are you running behind a proxy? can you post the log of "mvn clean install". On first build maven needs to download quite a few plugins and dependencies from a maven repository.

Comment: @MayankSharma That simply means that you enabled the maven-ear-plugin in your POM but you didn't specify the version. It's missing!

Comment: I resolved it.. There was no jar in the local repository folder(with the version ID that was mentioned) I changed the version id to the jar which was present. It got resolved. Thanks :)